# Binding a list variable into a new data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` version 0.4.1, and am trying to wrap my head around list variables.

I am having trouble creating a new data frame (or a `tbl_df` or `data_frame` or whatever) from a table containing a list variable.

For example, if I have a `tbl_df` like so:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(3,2,1)
d <- data_frame(X = list(x, y))

d
## Source: local data frame [2 x 1]
##
##         X
## 1 <dbl[3]>
## 2 <dbl[3]>
```

Assuming all the values of the list variable `X` is the same length or dimensions, is there an operation that I can run to create a table that looks like `rbind(x, y)` from the list variable inside the table?

I am hoping to get something that will look like:

```
data_frame(V1 = c(1, 3), V2 = c(2, 2), V3 = c(3, 1))
## Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
##
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1  1  2  3
## 2  3  2  1
```

The closest I got to to my desired result was a stacked column:

```
d %>% tidyr::unnest(X)
```

I thought that maybe using `rowwise` to group by row might allow me to do an operation for each row, but I am seeing the same results as above.

```
d %>% rowwise %>% tidyr::unnest(X) # %>% some extra commands here??
```

Comment: You want a `tbl_df` I presume?  You show a matrix

Comment: a `tbl_df` would be desirable. I'll change my question to be extra clear.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, list(x,y))` that was suggested by @mkemp6 seems like the correct and most efficient solution. Trying to do *everything* with `dplyr` is just crazy IMO. With `data.table` you could do `library(data.table) ; as.data.frame(t(rbindlist(d)))`, but the `t` part seems like a big overhead.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Right, I understand that. I am just experimenting with new functionality in `dplyr`. Also, on a little bit of a tangent, I do not like calling `do.call(rbind, list(...))` as it performs quite slowly on large data sets, and prefer either `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Comment: `bind_rows` won't work in this case, while `rbindlist` will require `t` (as already illustrated), I think that this `t` will be a huge overhead as the data goes bigger. From my experience `do.call` is quite efficient

Comment: @DavidArenburg From my experience, combining a number of large `data.frames` in a list using `do.call` is very slow. Due to this bottleneck, I started using the `data.table` package in one of my projects!

Comment: The problem here, is that you are not exactly having normal `data.frmes` here

Comment: You can do `setDT(transpose(d$X))[]` from data.table v1.9.5.

Comment: @ialm I don't get why you're using list variables here. They just make life more difficult in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a little work on `d` first, then use `bind_rows()`

```
library(dplyr)
d$X %>% 
    lapply(function(x) data.frame(matrix(x, 1))) %>%
    bind_rows
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  3  2  1
```

Another way is to use `tbl_dt` after `rbindlist()`, which can also be fed into `dplyr` functions

```
library(data.table)
tbl_dt(rbindlist(lapply(d$X, as.list)))
# Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  3  2  1
```

Comment: What if I have the vectors in a `tbl_df` as a list variable? I know how to create a `tbl_df` if I have the vectors `x` and `y`. It seems that getting them out of the `tbl_df` and into a `tbl_df` seems more trouble than its worth.